# Customizing Mat-datepicker

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

Trying to customize the calendar icon to make it appear inside the text box , If I try to add css I'm not getting it responsive, I have attached my current output and desired output

Expected Output

[image: 1]

Current Output

[image: 2]

Comment: Is the mat-datepicker in a formfield or is it a normal text-input?  show us your template or make a stackblitz please.

Comment: Yes, the mat-datepicker is a form field

Comment: it's only use matDatepickerToggleIcon, see the example about this in https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples. NOTE: You can use a mat-icon, or a div or an imagen. You can also use style="margin-left:-15px" in the "tag" that make the toogle

Answer (score 0):

You can use appearance="outline". The datepicker icon is in the inner of the mat-form-field border.

Try this:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>Outline form field</mat-label>
  <input matInput placeholder="Placeholder" [matDatepicker]="myDatepicker">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="myDatepicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #myDatepicker></mat-datepicker>
  <mat-hint>Hint</mat-hint>
</mat-form-field>
```

See: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pbgfuc?file=src/app/form-field-appearance-example.html)

Comment: I tried using this solution but it remains the same as previous one